# Get nth button in a jquery-ui buttonset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

Is there some way to get the nth button in a jquery-ui buttonset?

```js
$( "#radio" ).buttonset();
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio">
      <input type="radio" id="sizzle" name="project">
      <label for="sizzle">Sizzle</label>
 
      <input type="radio" id="qunit" name="project" checked="checked">
      <label for="qunit">QUnit</label>
 
      <input type="radio" id="color" name="project">
      <label for="color">Color</label>
</div>
```

I can select button qunit using its id selector.

But is there any way to select say the 2nd button in this set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can select it in jQuery

```
$("#radio input[type=radio]").eq(1)
```

OR

```
$("#radio input[type=radio]").get(1)
```

OR

```
$("#radio input[type=radio]:eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can alway use jquery selectors like [**:eq**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```js
$("#radio :radio:eq(1)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="sizzle" name="project">
  <label for="sizzle">Sizzle</label>

  <input type="radio" id="qunit" name="project" checked="checked">
  <label for="qunit">QUnit</label>

  <input type="radio" id="color" name="project">
  <label for="color">Color</label>
</div>
```

Alternative:

```
$("#radio :radio:nth-child(1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = 2;
var nthButton = $( "#radio input[type='radio']" ).buttonset().eq(n);
```

Adding `input[type='radio']` selects the radio buttons themselves instead of the container div, `eq(n)` selects only the nth button.